# Libsodium installation issue: Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'sodium.so' in Unknown on line 0 ....

Tags: libsodium

I've been struggling since days to install libsodium on my Debian9/php7.0(with fpm) server ...
When I follow the steps outlined on https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/00-intro.md#installing-libsodium everything seems to work, however I get this error at PHP startup:

Invalid library (maybe not a PHP library) 'sodium.so' in Unknown on line 0 ....

So the extension is not loaded ...

Hope someone can help me,
Thx !
Vincent.

Answer (score 1):

Use

`pecl install -f libsodium-2.0.8`

to install version 2.0.8, that should work perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it was a version issue as per the feedback I got here:

https://github.com/paragonie/halite/issues/48